# Discord webhook sends along with previous messages problem in python

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import csv
import os

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discordapp.c.........')


file_name = 'symbols.csv'
all_data = []
def load_csv():
    with open(file_name, 'r') as dict:
        rows = csv.DictReader(dict)
        for row in rows:
            all_data.append(row)

load_csv()
while True:
    coinname = (input("ENTER COINNAME: ")).upper()                    
    if coinname:
        for data in all_data:
            if data['BASE'].strip()  == coinname.strip():
                embed = DiscordEmbed(title=f'{coinname}/USDT', description=f'**{coinname}**', color=65280, url=f'https://www.binance.com/en/trade/{coinname}_USDT?layout=pro')
                print(f"[+] Message: {embed}")
                webhook.add_embed(embed)
                response = webhook.execute()
                print(response)
                os.system('cls')
```

There is no problem in the first input, but when it works for the second time, it sends the first embed message and the last embed message together.

for example:
input 1:
eth

output 1:
ETH/USDT
ETH

input 2:
btc

output 2:
ETH/USDT
ETH

BTC/USDT
BTC

How can i get this output?

input 1:
eth

output 1:
ETH/USDT
ETH

input 2:
btc

output 2:
BTC/USDT
BTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webhook.add_embed(embed)` adds new embed to the webhook, and you are not removing it before next iteration
you should place this line inside your `while` loop

```
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discordapp.c.........')
```

or somehow remove embed from your `webhook` variable after sending it